# How do I set up a local environment in visual studio code to run U-SQL without being connected to the Azure DataLake?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, u-sql

This is my code to eliminate null cells and duplicate Function rows while also keeping the Product column properly aligned with the Function column. I just want to keep the first occurrence of the Function and remove any duplicates.It compiles just fine, but I can't find my output. Someone suggested I simply click on the outputted jobURL but that is not working for me properly. Here is a sample file that is a small slice of the full spreadsheet and only includes data in the 2 relevant columns. The full spreadsheet has data in all columns. https://www.dropbox.com/s/auu2aco4b037xn7/Function.csv?dl=0

```
@input = 
    EXTRACT 
        CompanyID             string,
        division              string,
        store_location        string,
        International_Id      string,
        Function              string,
        office_location       string,
        address               string,
        Product               string,
        Revenue               string,
        sales_goal            string,
        Manager               string,
        Country               string

    FROM "/input/input142.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1 );


// Remove empty columns
@working =
    SELECT *
    FROM @input
    WHERE Function.Length > 0;


// Rank the columns by Function and keep only the first one
@working =
    SELECT CompanyID,
           division,
           store_location,
           International_Id,
           Function,
           office_location,
           address,
           Product,
           Revenue,
           sales_goal,
           Manager,
           Country
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Function ORDER BY Product) 
AS rn
    FROM @working
) AS x
WHERE rn == 1;


@output = SELECT * FROM @working;

OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

Here are my desired results:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o82eskycbq1i1ss/Function_desired_result.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-local-run

check this document if you want to run/debug your scripts locally